# Why does Firebase delete data automatically on logout?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Android, I use `Firebase` for user login through a phone number and Google.
Now when I sign in through the phone number and Google it works fine, but the problem is when I **logout the account associated with that phone number the account data is deleted from Firebase**. But no data gets deleted from Firebase when I authorize through Google.

My question is: why is the data removed when I use verified phone number and logout?

Comment: at  least 10people edited my question but no one answered it.is it so hard or there is no answer for this. shame for this site @stack-overflow

Comment: Logout should not affect the user. It should definitely not delete it. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @UttamMeerwal: Yes, you should demand they pay your money back.